# How to send a socket data using udp without converting to bytes in c#

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I need to send a `String` data(with out converting to byte[]) to be sent to all system (both android devices) in a network (broadcasting). where ever I am searching for this, in all code they are using byte conversion. and while i am using `StreamWritter` for sending string data `StreamWritter` is not supporting broadcasting method. Please help me for this.

Comment: you need to transmit the data as bytes and then reconstruct the bytes into a string when the data is received.

Comment: but here the problem is the receivers are android app.. and its a already build app. it will accept only string values..

Comment: do you have receivers source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android apps are also only receiving bytes on the transport layer (UDP). As these apps already exist you have to know what kind of encoding they expect (ASCII, UTF-8 ...) and send the string with the needed encoding.

On the Android side these bytes are converted with the encoding to the string that is then used by the app.

If the app uses a specific protocol on top of UDP you could search for an existing implementation in C# for this protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
Sockets are not dealing with strings, so long story short, you have to translate it to string back on the other side.

Comment: you can use any method, but the end result should is string should be send by broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's impossible.
The android receiver will have a method that will convert bytes from the stream into a string. Find out how it does it, and reverse the process when you encode.

Generally this'll be the string converted to it's byte[] representation with a int prefixed to it telling you the size of the string.